# Background colour wont appear behind list items

Tags: css, html, user-interface

For some reason my list items are not sitting within my UL element which is disturbing the flow of the page, and doesn't look right. I have tried every position element under the sun but nothing works. I wondered is it because I'm styling a different div instead of the UL element?

Please see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc5cr/)

The red border is suppose to hold the list elements and if one list description becomes longer, then the red background should grow as well.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
ol, ul
{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc5cr/8/

Answer (score 1):

Your `LI` have `float` in it so you have to clear his parent which is `UL`. Write like this:

```
ul{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Uc5cr/1/

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the LI elements are floating, and therefor going over the UL outlines. You'd typically solve this by clearing your LI elements with a element using `clear: left;` property in CSS, when you want to clear the floating.

But since this is in an un-ordered list, it is probably best to use a CSS hack called "clearfix" on your UL-element to solve this. That way the UL element will follow the LI elements in height.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mikaelbr/JkGRj/

*Note: There are many versions of the clearfix hack. Do a google search to find some, if you are interessted in seeing how they work.*

Answer (score 0):

give overflow:hidden to the div erd background in order to contain the ul element
Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Uc5cr/7/